# Refreshing the browser bypasses angular on routerProvider based URLs

Tags: grails, angularjs

I have a grails app backing an angularjs front-end.  They are deployed as a single WAR.  I've removed the context path from the app so that it runs on `http://localhost:8080`.

I have a list of articles and I have the `$routeProvider` setup to redirect `/` to `/articles` at which point the controller takes over and pulls the list via `$http`.  Pretty standard stuff.

Initially, I was using the default location provider config in that hashes `(#)` are used in the URL.  I've changed it via

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and everything still works.  However, if I change the URL directly in the address bar and hit enter, or if I just refresh the browser when it is at /articles, the server side takes over and I just get my list of articles as json.  No angular.  I understand why this happens and for now what I've done is detected a non-ajax request on the server and am issuing a redirect to `/` which will allow angular to kick into gear.

I'm wondering if this is the right thing.  Or is there something else I can do that is a better practice.

Comment: There a reason why you can't use the standard way with the `#`s?

Comment: Not really.  I'm just trying to learn angularjs and am trying different approaches to see what works best for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirecting is the right solution.

I was able to make it work using url mapping. So far it works :-)

I started with something like this:

```
"/**" (controller: 'app', action: 'index')
```

with app/index being the angular app page. But this will also match everything else (e.g. /$controller/$action). I had to explicitly map each $controller/$action to the correct controller. Not so good... ;-)

To solve this problem I'm prefixing all uris with `/client` for angular routes and `/server` for grails uris. This makes url mapping easy and it helps to distinguish angular routes from template uris etc.

My final url mapping looks like this:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static excludes = [
        "/lib/**",
        "/css/**",
        "/js/**"
    ]

    static mappings = {
        // - all client uris (routes) will start with '/client/',
        // - all server uris (load)   will start with '/server/'

        // redirect /$appName/ to /$appName/client
        "/" (controller: 'redirect', action: 'redirectTo') {
            to = '/client/'
            permanent = true
        }

        // redirect any angular route       
        "/client/**" (controller: 'app', action: 'index')


        // standard controller/action mapping
        "/server/$controller/$action/$id?"  {
            constraints {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can't redirect directly in the url mapping, so I use a simple controller:

```
class RedirectController {
    def redirectTo () {
        redirect (uri: params.to, permanent: params.permanent)
    }
}
```

The routing entries look like this:

```
$routeProvider.when ('/client/login', {templateUrl: './server/security/login'});
```

Answer (score 0):

just answered on this question here
[angularjs html5mode refresh page get 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895675/angularjs-html5mode-refresh-page-get-404)

be sure that you **rewrite rules** on server work correctly