# Elastic Beanstalk: remove hashbang urls from SPA

Tags: angularjs, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AngularJS app hosted using Elastic Beanstalk and I'd like to remove the hashbangs (#!) from urls, but am having trouble using config files to make the necessary modifications to the Apache server.

I have enabled html5mode in my angular app and I currently have the following config file in my .ebextensions directory

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgirewrite.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        RewriteEngine On  
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]  
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d  
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Everything works fine without the hashbangs until I reload the page and I get a 404 indicating that the rewrite rules aren't working.

If possible, I'd like to avoid any solutions that involve ssh, copying, and modifying one of the default configs as this will likely make maintenance a nightmare if AWS changes any defaults down the road

Comment: how did you deploy your application? eb cli? or via the console?

Comment: Deployed using eb cli

Comment: and you have changed the config of your local development environment to remove the hastags ?

Comment: no I haven't figured out how to do that either.  I'm using Python Flask's development server locally so modifying it will be different than modifying the prod apache server, and getting it working in prod is the immediate priority so just havent invested the time

Answer (score 0):

Hashbang is a fallback mechanism for older browsers, where HTML5 is not supported. Check illustration:

[image: Hashbang fallback]

What you may be looking for is how to configure "pretty URLs" in AngularJS. Besides enabling HTML5 mode (which it seems you already did: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`), you need to configure the `<base href="/">` tag inside your `<head>`, specifying the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.

*Note: the $location service will automatically fallback to the hashbang method for browsers that do not support the HTML5 History API.*

By Angular's documentation, without #, the url looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites. This is the `httpd.conf` example they have for **Apache** server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Since you are working with **Beanstalk**, you need to config `httpd.conf` via [ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). Two options available for Apache:

- To **override** the Elastic Beanstalk default Apache configuration completely, include a configuration in your source bundle at `.ebextensions/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.
- To **extend** the Elastic Beanstalk default Apache configuration, add .conf configuration files to a folder named `.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d` in your application source bundle (e.g. `.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/port5000.conf`).

I would recommend the extension option.

References:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: The issue is not removing the hashbang from the urls - I am able to do that fine as I have already enabled html5 mode and set the base href - the issue is the 404 that I get when I try to refresh the page.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode/16570533#16570533  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895675/angularjs-html5mode-refresh-page-get-404

Comment: No luck, I went the extension route and created directory httpd/conf.d/ under .ebextensions.  Everything loads fine and works without the #! but when I reload I get the same 404

Comment: Are you sure you're using Apache? What language are you writing your code? PHP? Python? Java? Recommendations are different based on server: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Also, make sure you share all logs you find. Here's how you can request log from Beanstalk's EC2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: Positive I'm using Apache - I'm using a Flask app in a Python 2.7 environment, which means that the server is Apache 2.4.33 with mod_wsgi 3.5 according to these docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html

Comment: Also are you sure that conf file is in the right format for a ebextension?  I have another .conf file that enables HTTP auth headers to be passed to Flask and it has the following format  "files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgihacks.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On"